# What's the tag for Ubuntu Edge?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it [edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/edge) or [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch)? I guess it should be the first one, but it has no description and also was used before for screen edges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is already the tag [ubuntu-edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-edge) - I assume that would be the best to use ;)

It looks like [edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/edge) is being used far more generally than it probably should - out of the three questions that appear, one is for screen edges, one is for a Thinkpad Edge (computer model) and one is for a Sapphire Edge (another computer model). The more specific one seems far better to me.

Comment: EDGE is also another acronym for EGPRS (which becomes particularly relevant with a mobile Ubuntu).

Comment: This tag should be avoided altogether... is unhelpful.

Comment: @Braiam: which tag are you referring to?

Comment: @Flimm the [tag:edge] tag. I've checked out most of the questions, and they are a mess.