# What should be done with the 'edge' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There has been a discussion about it on the comments of [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7055/62483) but that is another question.

I think that this tag ([edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/edge)) is used for several case, such as mentioning a computer model, network service, or Ubuntu Edge. But it is not specified in the tag summary at all.

I'm a bit tired of review edits adding and removing this tag and I don't know what to do.

Should we create a synonym to [ubuntu-edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-edge) or delete this tag? Another suggestion?

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7054/169736 . Most of my edits are based on the suggestion posted here.

Comment: I've already pointed to the answer of that question. And yes, I saw many of your edits and they are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Please do not allow this tag to live!

There are too many things that use "edge" in it's name, and the system isn't smart enough to know if it will be really useful. Examples:

- Ubuntu-edge, the operative system.
- Edge of the monitor/tablet/screen/etc.
- Thinkpad edge,
- Edge swapping, a effect of compiz
- EDGE (Enhanced Data Rates for GSM Evolution) the digital mobile technology
- Edge, of a window.
- Others "edge"s of anything...

Because of this, this tag should be avoided/nuked.

If tags are needed to contain "edge" they should use the hyphen (-), example:

- [thinkpad-edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/thinkpad-edge) (I really do not make too much sense of this one... someone might)
- [egprs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/egprs) and in the excerpt/wiki say that is also know as EDGE
- no other case scenario where "edge" could be useful for looking at question/answer, and won't give headaches later.